# 1 button, plays 10 sounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, button, audio

1 button, plays 10 sounds?
How can I get a button to play some sounds in on order?

How can I add an extra sound to this action?

```
-(IBAction)sound1 
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: Do u know duration of all the sounds?

Comment: Why not concatenating the audio files and play one file? ;)

Comment: 2-3sec.
 I want to make a counting app, so on first touch it says 1 and on second touch 2. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the best luck with AVAudioPlayer - it's a library called AVFoundation you can import through "Build Phases" (first click on the blue xcode project name at top left) and then "Link Binary with Libraries"

Then try this really simple YouTube tutorial to make a button play sound:

http://youtu.be/kCpw6iP90cY

That's the same video I used 2 years ago to create my first sound board. Xcode 5 is a little different but the code will all work.

Ok now you need to create an array of these sounds that will cycle through them. Check out this link from TreeHouse:

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/creating-an-array-with-mp3-sound-files

Comment: I can't upvote the answer, because I'm not familiar with the subject matter, but if you post a link to the image you want to insert, I can insert it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the sounds are name sound0 … soundN, you can just introduce to ivars — one tracks the current index, one defines the number of sounds.

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSUInteger soundIdx; 
    NSUInteger soundCount;
}    

-(instancetype) init //or any other entry point method like viewDidLoad,....
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        soundCount = 10;
    }
    return self;
}


-(IBAction)sound 
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%lu", soundIdx], CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    soundIdx = (++soundIdx) % soundCount;

}
@end
```

---

If the sound names do not follow any particular naming convention, you could put them in an array

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSUInteger soundIdx; 
    NSArray *soundNames;
}    

-(instancetype) init //or any other entry point method like viewDidLoad,....
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        soundNames = @[@"sound1",@"hello", @"ping"];
    }
    return self;
}


-(IBAction)sound
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) soundNames[soundIdx], CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    soundIdx = (++soundIdx) % [soundNames count];

}    
@end
```